# Assigning values from an array to a separate variable in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C and currently building a unit converter. Everything works fine thus far but there's a slight issue. I've created an array of conversion rates for metric and imperial distances. The program assigns a value from this array to a separate variable based on the units the user wishes to convert and then does the necessary calculation to find the final amount. I've realised that there's so many different possible combinations of units to convert, I'd need to write a lot of else if statements for the program to be able to calculate all the possible conversions. I'm later going to add in functions that can convert mass, fluid units etc. which would require even more else if statements. I'm wondering how I can get around this, or will I just have to bear the brunt of writing God knows how many else if statements? Any help much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Global Variables
char inputUnit;
char outputUnit;
double inputDistance;
double outputDistance;

//Conversion rates for Metric to Imperial distances (and vice versa)
const double METRIC_IMPERIAL_CONV_RATE[][4] = {{25.4, 2.54, 0.0254, 0.0000254}, {304.8, 30.48, 0.3048, 0.0003048}, {914.4, 91.44, 0.9144, 0.000914}, {1609344, 160934.4, 1609.344, 1.609344}};

// Unit symbols
const char* DISTANCE_SYMBOLS[] = {"''", "ft", "yd", "mi", "mm", "cm", "m", "km"};

//Function Prototypes
double convertDistanceMI(double distance);

//Converts distances from Metric to Imperial (and vice versa)
double convertDistanceMI(double distance) {

    double convRate;
    double finalConversion;

    if (inputUnit == *DISTANCE_SYMBOLS[0] && outputUnit == *DISTANCE_SYMBOLS[4]) {
        convRate = METRIC_IMPERIAL_CONV_RATE[0][0]; 
        finalConversion = distance * convRate;}

    else if (inputUnit == *DISTANCE_SYMBOLS[4] && outputUnit == *DISTANCE_SYMBOLS[0]) {
        convRate = METRIC_IMPERIAL_CONV_RATE[0][0]; 
        finalConversion = distance / convRate;} 
    
    return finalConversion;
        
}


int main() {

    printf("Enter original unit symbol (use 2x single quotes for inches): ");
    scanf("%s", &inputUnit);

    printf("Enter new unit symbol (use 2x single quotes for inches): ");
    scanf("%s", &outputUnit);

    printf("Enter amount to 2 decimal places: ");
    scanf("%lf", &inputDistance);

    outputDistance = convertDistanceMI(inputDistance);

    printf("%f%s", outputDistance, outputUnit);
}
```

Comment: PSA: Stay **away** from global variables. There's absolutely no need for them here. Move those into `main()`. When we're looking at code, it's really frustrating to have to search around for type definitions, especially when they're a long, long way from where those variables are actually used. `inputUnit` and `outputUnit` should be arguments to your conversion functions.

Comment: I think you're trying to compare C strings with `==` which is not going to happen. You need `strcmp()`.

Comment: `inputUnit == *DISTANCE_SYMBOLS[4]` is probably not going to work as you expect. first of all `DISTANCE_SYMBOLS[4]` is the string `"mm"`, as in millimeter, not `"mi"` as in miles. Secondly you only compare the single character `inputUnit` with the single character `DISTANCE_SYMBOLS[4][0]`. So you compare only (for example) if `'m' == 'm'`.

Comment: `"%s"` is the wrong format specifier for a `char`, you need to use `"%c"` instead, or more likely change `inputUnit` and `outputUnit` to character arrays that have enough space to hold a string. You probably need size 3 for two `char`s of units plus a NUL terminator: `char inputUnit[3];`

Comment: @tadman thanks for the advice, I'll make the necessary changes. And when I run the code it actually works fine. You can convert inches to mm no problem and vice versa

Comment: Note: don't try to make all possible conversions by pairing them: choose a normalized unit (say U), then when converting from A to B, convert A to U and then U to B. You will only have 2n converters for n-units and not n^2!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am aware that `DISTANCE_SYMBOLS[4]` is "mm". Right now the program only converts inches to mm and vice versa, if you run the code it should work fine. It worked alright for me :)

Comment: If you want to have many converters, then you will probably need some data structure like `{(unit_name,converter_to_u,converter_from_u}`. That needs pointers to function.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thanks for the advice, I'll experiement with this and see what I can come up with :)

Comment: I suggest you convert from whatever input unit to a standard unit, then from you standard unit to  your desired output unit.  This means you need to write n + m conversion functions instead of n * m.  The other thing figure out how to make it data drive instead of code, then write a function to use the data for the conversion. Study  GNU units <https://www.gnu.org/software/units/>

Comment: You can probably read the nput value and unit in one prompt.  `if(scanf("%f%s", &value, str) != 2) { // handle error }'.

Answer (score 1):

The above comments probably led to the solution already.  In particular: use a structure, use a standard unit.  I rewrite the original program to better illustrate them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Conversion rates for Metric to Imperial distances (and vice versa)
const double METRIC_IMPERIAL_CONV_RATE[][4] =
{
    {25.4, 2.54, 0.0254, 0.0000254},
    {304.8, 30.48, 0.3048, 0.0003048},
    {914.4, 91.44, 0.9144, 0.000914},
    {1609344, 160934.4, 1609.344, 1.609344}
};

// Unit symbols
const char* DISTANCE_SYMBOLS[] = {"''", "ft", "yd", "mi", "mm", "cm", "m", "km"};

static const struct unit_conv
{
    char const *distance_symbol;
    double const metric_conv_rate;
} unit_conv[] =
{
    {"''", 0.0254},
    {"ft", 0.3048},
    {"yd", 0.09144},
    {"mi", 1609.344},
    {"mm", 0.001},
    {"cm", 0.01},
    {"m", 1},
    {"km", 1000},
    {NULL, 0} // sentinel
};

// Function Prototypes are not needed if the function is defined before being called

static double find_unit(char const *unit)
{
    for (int i = 0; unit_conv[i].distance_symbol; ++i)
        if (unit[0] == unit_conv[i].distance_symbol[0] &&
            unit[1] == unit_conv[i].distance_symbol[1]) // this is 0 for "m"
                return unit_conv[i].metric_conv_rate;

    return 0;
}

static double to_meters(char *inputUnit, double distance)
{
    double convRate = find_unit(inputUnit);
    return convRate * distance;
}

static double to_final(char *outputUnit, double meters)
{
    double convRate = find_unit(outputUnit);
    if (convRate)
        return meters / convRate;

    return 0;
}

int main() {
//local Variables
char inputUnit[4];
char outputUnit[4];
double inputDistance;
double outputDistance;

    printf("Enter original unit symbol (use 2x single quotes for inches): ");
    scanf("%2s", inputUnit);

    printf("Enter new unit symbol (use 2x single quotes for inches): ");
    scanf("%2s", outputUnit);

    printf("Enter amount to 2 decimal places: ");
    scanf("%lf", &inputDistance);

    outputDistance = to_final(outputUnit, to_meters(inputUnit, inputDistance));

    printf("%f%s\n", outputDistance, outputUnit);

    return 0;
}
```

Also note, `main()` must return an `int`, you can insert newlines wherever you like.

Comment: Note, in imperial units the double-quote `"` is used to denote inches (or tenth of inches) while the single-quote `'`is used to denote feet. Just a nit. (but otherwise nice answer) Probably a better solution for inches from a code perspective is just to use `"in"` for inches. Also note, when a new C programmer is struggling with refactoring large `if, else if, else ...` blocks -- it is likely they are not yet familiar with `struct` -- may spend an extra line or two explaining.

Comment: You must validate the conversions done with `scanf()` so you catch and handle *input* and *matching* failures (especially where numeric conversions are involved), e.g. `if (scanf("%lf", &inputDistance) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`. Good job providing the *field-width* modifier (e.g. `"%2s"`) to ensure you do not write beyond the array bounds of the array filled invoking *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: Error handling is certainly essential for understanding malfunctions.  This simple example just returns 0.